# Braid wiring diagrams and matroids

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry, discrete-mathematics

recently I started reading some articles about the presentation of the fundamental group of lines arrangements in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ via Wiring diagrams.

I also found some relation with matroid theory. In particular in the article of R. Cordovil and J. Fachada "Braid monodromy groups of wiring diagrams" are established some relations between matroid and braided wiring diagrams.

However, I'd like to find some suggestion and discuss in order to extend these relation to matroid to oriented or complex matroid.

Comment: what is your question here? are you asking for some references? please specify your question!

Answer (score 5):

It is a bit unclear what you seek,
but perhaps it will help to
note that there is a 1-1 correspondence between wiring diagrams and *allowable sequences*,
as [this AMS Feature Column](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-oriented5)
describes.

---

[image: rhombdual]

 
 
 
 
 
<sup>(Image from [this website](http://www.quazoo.com/q/Oriented_matroid).)</sup>

---

A source on this topic is this ~200-page (downloadable)
book, which has ~350 bibliographic references:

> Cohen, Dan, Graham Denham, Michael Falk, Hal Schenck, Alex Suciu, Hiro Terao, and Sergey Yuzvinsky. *Complex Arrangements: Algebra, Geometry, Topology*. (2009).
>   [PDF download link](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~schenck/cxarr.pdf)

The Cordovil & Fachada paper you cite is reference [64] in this book.

Comment: New link to the PDF: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/239606930_Complex_Arrangements_Algebra_Geometry_Topology